# 16S rRNA and 5S rRNA datasets

Tags: bioinformatics, database, rrna

I need 16S rRNA and 5S rRNA (Gammaproteobacteria - E.coli) Secondary structure files in ct format.

I tried looking for them in different RNA databases, could not find one. Can someone tell me where to find such datasets?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This site](http://apollo.chemistry.gatech.edu/RibosomeGallery/index.html) has secondary structure maps for rRNA from different organisms but they are just pictures. Not sure if it is helpful.

Comment: Thanks. But I was looking for the secondary structure files in ct format. I found it in RNA STRAND v2.0, please check the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

RNA STRAND v2.0 - The RNA secondary STRucture and statistical ANalysis Database
http://www.rnasoft.ca/strand/

16S rRNA: secondary structure file in ct format

http://www.rnasoft.ca/strand/show_file.php?format=CT&molecule_ID=CRW_00111&check_out_the=View+the+RNA+sequence+and+secondary+structure+for+molecule+CRW_00111

5S rRNA: secondary structure file in ct format

http://www.rnasoft.ca/strand/show_file.php?format=CT&molecule_ID=CRW_00573&check_out_the=View+the+RNA+sequence+and+secondary+structure+for+molecule+CRW_00573